# Forward and backward work distributions in fluctuation theorem

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Fluctuation theorems such as Jarzynski equality and Crooks theorem ([Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crooks_fluctuation_theorem)), show that

$\frac{P_f(W)}{P_b(-W)}=\,exp[\beta(W- \,\Delta F)]$

where $W$ is work done on the system during each transformation , $P_f$ and $P_b$ represent work distribution of forward and backward dynamics respectively.

Seeing several articles I noticed that $P_f$ and $P_b$ are symmetric, with respect to the point $W = \Delta F$ i.e. when they are extrapolated into Gaussian-type distribution, both have same standard deviation but different mean. In plain molecular dynamics simulation, it seems to be plausible.

However when it comes to, for example, a system of damped springs being pulled (forward process) and randomly interacting with adjacent particles (kind of thermostat) can we still insist that $P_f$ and $P_b$ be symmetric? If time duration of both processes is same velocity profile of the system during backward (pushing) process would be wider than that during forward process which may result in unwanted behaviors. Furthermore there is no guarantee that influence of thermostatting dynamics is same on both processes.

Nevertheless, work distribution diagrams in the articles does not show any asymmetric shapes (such as narrow backward/broad forward distributions) even if when they deal with generalized Langevin dynamics which contains dissipative, random portion.

Is there any thesis that concerns asymmetric distributions(I'm not curious about asymmetry of each distributions but relative shape of them)? Or, should I admit equivalent standard deviation of two distributions?